# Regular Expression for 3 Digits, having leading zeros?

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am in search for a regular expression that will satisfy the following cases:

Valid:
`001  where ones place can be 0-9`
`011  where ones and tens place can be 0-9`
`111  where all places can be 0-9`

Invalid:
`1`
`11`

I'm not very good as grouping these expressions which is where I'm lost. I can do the basic stuff but getting this type of specifics is way out of my league. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Start with this http://www.addedbytes.com/download/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet-v2/png/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To simplify your question, it looks like you want a value between 0 and 999 and *must* be left padded with zeros if it is less than 100.

Try `\d{3}`

Comment: This works like a charm! such a simple and short answer..i expected something horrible :) haha

Comment: This was not working for me,  it would not fail the value '1234'.   What did work was ^\d{3}$